# Error in Netbeans: "Cannot find an HtmlParser implementation for HTML5"

Tags: 12.04, netbeans

When I open a file in Netbeans, I get a `Please wait...` on the first line of in the editor window.

I also get an exception icon at the bottom of the screen which says:

```
A org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.ParseException exception has occurred.
However, the system should continue working without further problems.
Click Show Details for the stack trace.
```

If I click on "show more details", I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find an HtmlParser implementation for HTML5
    at org.netbeans.editor.ext.html.parser.api.SyntaxAnalyzerResult.findParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.editor.ext.html.parser.api.SyntaxAnalyzerResult.doParseHtml(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.editor.ext.html.parser.api.SyntaxAnalyzerResult.parseHtml(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.api.gsf.HtmlParserResult.root(HtmlParserResult.java:133)
    at org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.api.gsf.HtmlParserResult.roots(HtmlParserResult.java:172)
    at org.netbeans.modules.html.editor.gsf.HtmlStructureScanner.folds(HtmlStructureScanner.java:158)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.addTree(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.editor.BaseDocument.render(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.scan(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callUserTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager$UserTaskAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.filebasedfs.utils.FileChangedManager.priorityIO(FileChangedManager.java:168)
    at org.netbeans.modules.masterfs.providers.ProvidedExtensions.priorityIO(ProvidedExtensions.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.Utilities.runPriorityIO(Unknown Source)
Caused: org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.ParseException
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.runUserTask(Unknown Source)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.api.ParserManager.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.gsfFoldScan(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.csl.editor.fold.GsfFoldManager$JavaElementFoldTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callParserResultTask(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I am using the stock NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 which is available directly from the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with my php application; it said please wait... at the top of the page and wouldn't let me edit the file properly.

I realised that NetBeans thought the project was in HTML5 which isn't supported by NetBeans 7.0.1 so I clicked on "please wait..." and selected to use an older version of HTML as the project's default. Hey presto, worked straight away!

Comment: That does work, but how do I get HTML5 to work.  I would like to do some HTML5 development on NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug from the Netbeans versions in the Ubuntu repositories (NetBeans 7.0.1).

Install a newer version directly from https://netbeans.org/downloads/ and it will work OK.